# What does $\oplus $ mean in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is this operation in (b) part ?

Comment: I would guess it's symmetric difference of sets. However, the book (or whatever it is you are reading) should at one point define this symbol.

Comment: I would guess it it set union. This is usually denoted $\bigcup$.

Comment: Disjoint union perhaps? But I am sure the book has a definition somewhere.

Comment: I don't have the book. It's an assignment question.

Answer (score 2):

From the context, it is *most likely* symmetric difference.   The $\oplus$ symbol is normally used to denote "exclusive or" in (boolean) logic.   More usually the $\triangle$ symbol is used to distinguish between set-operation and logic-operation.

$$\begin{align}A\oplus B ~ = ~ A\triangle B = & ~ \Big\{x: (x\in A)\oplus (x\in B)\Big\} \\[1ex] = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B) = & ~ \Big\{x: \big((x\in A)\wedge(x\notin B)\big)\vee\big((x\notin A)\wedge (x\in B)\big)\Big\}\\[1ex] = ~ (A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^\complement = & ~ \Big\{x: \big((x\in A)\vee(x\in B)\big)\wedge\neg\big((x\in A)\wedge (x\in B)\big)\Big\}\end{align}$$